# What is the error in the service file?

Tags: systemd, services

I have a .NET Core application (self contained) which I've copied to the folder `/home/ubuntu/TimberApi` in an Ubuntu LightSail instance. I am trying to start it as a service. It is complaining that the unit file is invalid. Can anyone spot an error in the file?

This is the contents of the service file:

```
Description=Timber Store Api

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/TimberApi
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/TimberApi/TimberStore.Api
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=offershare-web-app
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the error:

```
Failed to start TimberStoreApi.service: Unit TimberStoreApi.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status TimberStoreApi.service' for details.
```

I ran `systemctl status TimberStoreApi.service` and got this:

```
/etc/systemd/system/TimberStoreApi.service:5: WorkingDirectory= path is not absolute: ~/TimberApi
```

Comment: Is TimberStore.Api an executable?

Comment: Should be an executable @Alex (because it runs when I type ./TimberStore.Api). Forgive me for my lack of understanding about linux file types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the `Working Directory` line *used to be* `WorkingDirectory=~/TimberApi` but has been edited to its current form `WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/TimberApi` without running `systemctl daemon-reload` afterwards, so `systemd` is still using the old version.

So just running `systemctl daemon-reload` should fix it.

If you use the `systemctl edit <some.service>` command, it will automatically execute `systemctl daemon-reload` for you when needed. But if you edit the service files directly, then you'll have to run `systemctl daemon-reload`, or else your changes won't take effect until you reboot the system.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It used to be ~/TimberApi. I have tried "systemctl daemon-reload" a few times, but it stiill gives me the same error unfortunately. I even rebooted the machine.

Comment: That is strange. Try running `cat -A /etc/systemd/system/TimberStoreApi.service`. It will make any invisible non-space characters visible: each end-of-line will be marked with an `$`,  any control characters will appear as regular characters with a `^` prefixed to them, and other special characters are displayed with a `M-` prefix. If you have edited the file in Windows, you might now see `^M$` at the end of each line: it means the file has Windows-style end-of-line characters, and you might want to convert the file to Unix-style end-of-lines, using e.g. `fromdos` or `dos2unix` commands.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response @telcoM. For some reason, my previous edit hadn't been saved. Now the service starts successfully.